# How to know if a file is text rendering or not? (Java)

Tags: java, file-io

How can I know at run time if the file in a specified folder is text rendering or not? (i.e files like csv, html, etc that can be displayed as text)

I do not want to do this via extension matching (by checking for .txt, .html extensions etc).

Suppose if there is a jpg file, I deliberately rename the extension to .txt and still the java code should be able to detect that this file (although with .txt extn) cannot be rendered as text.

How can I achieve this in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could guess the type by scanning the file and usinng [Character.html#isISOControl](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl%28char%29) to check whether there are non printable character included.

Binary files usually include headers which often contain control chars see this [list of File Signatures](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) most of them would be detected by isISOControl.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a heuristic matcher which scans files for known signatures.

One classic example is the `file` command: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command) and the libmagic library.

There are several variants in Java, such as Tika: http://tika.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a 100% foolproof way to do this, since it's a matter of opinion what counts as "can be displayed as text" ... but if you're okay with restricting it to English text, you could examine the bytes of the file, and if most or all of the byte values are in the range of 32 through 126 (decimal unsigned), then it is likely [vanilla ASCII text](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is going call for some kind of statistical pattern matching. You could, for example, if you were working with English only, check how many "foreign" characters appear in the first 100 characters. That should give you a pretty good idea of whether this is a text document or not. If you run into too many characters that are not a..zA..Z0..9[punctutation], then you can guess it is not text.  Working with English-language files, and languages that can be expressed using mostly the ASCII list of characters, you should be relatively safe.

This of course goes out the window the moment you start working with foreign languages where some of the characters might appear to be special characters, but only to someone who does not speak the language.

The other alternative is to use file markers (like in Java a class file starts with a specific header) and compare the values in the file to a library of headers. It's cumbersome and error-prone as well, as you might not have the file on record and could therefore think it's a text file when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The use of [a Character#isISOControl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl%28int%29) is a good thing. You should take the encoding in consideration too (p.ex.UTF-8). Here my function:

```
/**
 * Test is a file is a text file. It is the case only if it has no well-known control characters.
 * (see {@link Character#isISOControl(int)})
 * @param file
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static boolean isTextFile (final File file) throws IOException
{
    BufferedInputStream is = null;
    try
    {
        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-16"));

        boolean isText;
        int read;
        do
        {
            read = in.read();
            isText = read == -1;
            isText |= read == 13;  // newline
            isText |= read == 10;  // newline
            isText |= read == 9;   // tab
            isText |= !Character.isISOControl(read);
        }
        while (isText && read != -1);

        return isText;
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null)
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new Error(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can maintain a list of acceptable Mime Types and then get Mime Type of file you are reading. If it matches good to go.

```
import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
import java.io.File;

class GetMimeType {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    File f = new File("gumby.gif");
    System.out.println("Mime Type of " + f.getName() + " is " +
                         new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f));
    // expected output :
    // "Mime Type of gumby.gif is image/gif"
  }
}
```

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html

Comment: This would be via extension. Mime type is not inferred from contents.

Comment: `MimetypesFileTypeMap` is bad! How can it have a mimetype for a file that doesn't exist? This means it basically checks the extension. (Not my downvote)

Comment: @YannRamin Yeah my bad, just tested the code, thats bad...thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mob Yeah my bad, just tested the code, thats bad...thanks for pointing it out